# Python - Google Sheets API - Not Writing to the Specified Range

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets-api

I'm scraping some data from web and writing it to a Google Spreadsheet.
After a long DuckDuckGo'ing I'm asking for your help.

Libraries I use for this script:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import date, timedelta
```

The code below is in `for i in range(3)` loop.

Even when I write `range='Sheet1!E:G'` manually, it still begins writing from the column A.

When I replace the sheet name with another one, it appends values to that specific sheet, bu still not using the specified range. I've tried various ranges but still no good.

```
    SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
    spreadsheet_id = '*******'
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

        values = [
            [
                max_temp, avg_temp, min_temp
            ]

        ]
        body = {
            'values': values
        }

        range_list = ['B:D','E:G','H:J']
        range_name = f'Sheet1!{range_list[i]}'

        sheet = service.spreadsheets()
        result = sheet.values().append(
            spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name,
            valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED', body=body).execute()
```

HELP!!!

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer @Tanaike ! Sorry I was very busy and couldn't work on this project for days. I actually need it to work as it is said. So I don't want to use any workaround. I think I'll try to use 'update' instead of 'append' until Google fixes this problem. (Or tell us the right way to use their API)

Comment: Thank you for replying. If I misunderstand your reply, please tell me. My answer was not useful for your situation because you want to use ``values().append()``. If my understanding is correct, I think that I apologize about it and I have to delete my answer. If I misunderstood your reply, I apologize. By the way, can I ask you about ``tell us the right way to use their API``?

Comment: I was talking about Google representatives :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

- You want to put the values of `[[max_temp, avg_temp, min_temp]]` to the columns B-C, E-G and H-J.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- If [`values.append`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) is used, when `[[max_temp, avg_temp, min_temp]]` and `'Sheet1!B:D'` are used as the value and range, respectively, the values are put to the columns A-C. Even if the range of `'Sheet1'` is used, the result is the same.
- To write `[[max_temp, avg_temp, min_temp]]` to the column B-C, there are 2 ways:

  1. When the last row supposes 10, it uses `'Sheet1!B11'` as the range.

     - In this case, it is required to know the last row.
  2. When the range of is used `'Sheet1!B:D'`, it uses `[["", max_temp, avg_temp, min_temp]]` as the value.

     - In this case, although the values are put to the last row, when the values added the empty elements to the top of array, there is the case that the values are not put to the correct positions.

In my environment, I had been confused in this situation before. So I thought of a workaround and resolved my issue. In this workaround, the method of [`AppendCellsRequest`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#appendcellsrequest) of [`spreadsheets.batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) is used. I think that there might be several workarounds for your situation, so please think of this as just one of them.

#### Modified script:

Please update your script (after `service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))`) to the following lines:

```
spreadsheet_id = "#####"  # Please set spreadsheet ID here.
sheetId = 0  # Please set sheet ID here.
values = [[max_temp, avg_temp, min_temp]]
range_list = [1, 4, 7]  # columns B, E and H. First index is 0.
rows = [{'values': ([{}] * e) + [{'userEnteredValue': {'stringValue': r}} for r in values[0]]} for e in range_list]
body = {'requests': [{'appendCells': {'rows': rows, 'sheetId': 0, 'fields': "userEnteredValue.stringValue"}}]}
result = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=body).execute()
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that your environment can use Sheets API.
- When you use this script, please set sheet ID of `Sheet1` and set the values to `max_temp, avg_temp, min_temp`.
- `range_list = [1, 4, 7]` means columns B, E and H. In this case, the 1st index is 0.
- In this modified script, all values of `range_list` are created as the request body and used. By this, the values can be put by one API call. So `for i in range(3)` in your question can be removed.
- This is a sample modification. So please modify to your situation.

#### References:

- [spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)
- [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [AppendCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#appendcellsrequest)

If I misunderstood your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: @tehhowch Thank you for editing. I would like to study from it.